Deserializing a JSON object that doesn't work if there are uppercase letters
I have that class
package com.akensys.testlucas.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
public class Vetement {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private int code;
    private String sku;
    }

In postman i send http://localhost:8081/user/addJSON :
{
    "code":1310695,
    "sku":"524080012403"
}

All its okay i have the code and sku : Vetement(id=null, code=1310695, sku=524080012403)
But if my JSON looks like that :
{
    "CODE":1310695,
    "SKU":"524080012403"
}

And if I modify my class : code to CODE and sku to SKU It still doesn't work
I need to keep the JSON with name in uppercase so how can i make it works and why it doesnt work ?

In JSON "code" and "CODE" are two different keys. Is the all-uppercase version consistent, or do you need the same model object (Vetement) to work with both uppercase and lowercase keys? Have you read the docs at https://jakarta.ee/specifications/jsonb/2.0/jakarta-jsonb-spec-2.0.html#customizing-property-names on customizing the property names?

You can configure your ObjectMapper to allow this by setting the property, ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, to true.

But configure() of ObjectMapper is deprecated. If you are using the latest version of Spring, you could configure the same via JsonMapper.

I believe you are using Spring's default Jackson library. If so, fix it by configuring your application.yml like the following:
spring:
  jackson:
    mapper:
      ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES: true

via application.properties
  spring.jackson.mapper.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES=true

And finally, test your application well.


You can also configure the same via Java configuration, like below:
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
        return mapper;
    }

(Note: method configure() is deprecated)


If you are using the latest version of Spring, you can achieve the same via Java configuration, like below:
    @Bean
    public JsonMapper jsonMapper() {
        JsonMapper jm = JsonMapper.builder()
                .configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true)
                .build();
        return jm;
    }

